# Chrome Extensions - Embed Icons into Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to write a Chrome extension that embeds icons into pages and displays a pop-up when moused-over, similar to the functionaly provided by the [Tweetbeat Firsthand](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jgepnjcnamgjgmmlonednfonidanijpo) extension. I've had a look at the developer docs but I can't seem to find a description of how to embed icons in a page. Could you point me to a description of the API to do this or, better, a tutorial?

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: It's just a plain javascript task, no Chrome API involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the perfect job for a [Chrome content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). Just use something like JQuery to manipulate the DOM to add an `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Jquery.  Say you have to embed the icon around a target element, you can do like:

```
var iconHtml = "<img src=\"" + chrome.extension.getURL("img/yourIcon.png") + "\"/>";
$("#targetElementId").prepend($(iconHtml));
```

But it should be injected within a page by a script say inject.js, and needs to be invoked based on your logic(onload, menu click etc).

Also, that script needs to be defined in manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*"],
            "js": ["js/inject.js"]
        }
    ]
```

Hope it helps!